# How to step through multiple arrays then aggregating them

Tags: javascript, iteration, aggregate

I have an Object say Person.  Say I have Person.pets.breeds.ages.  Pets, breeds and ages are all arrays of objects.  If I want to aggregate all the ages what is the most efficient and cleanest way of doing so without making a bunch of for loops?  I really don't want to write a function like so:

```
   var result = []
   
   for (var j in pets) {
     var pet = pets[j]
     for (var k in breeds) {
       var breed = breeds[k]
       for (var l in ages) {
         result.push(ages[l])
       }
     }
   }
   return result
```

Comment: What exactly is your expected result if you push only `ages` to the result array?

Comment: It's supposed to be `pet.breeds` and `breed.ages` right?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it without a bunch of for loops is to utilize [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const person = {
  pets: [{
    breeds: [{
      ages: [{
        age: 1
      }]
    }, {
      ages: [{
        age: 2
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    breeds: [{
      ages: [{
        age: 3
      }]
    }, {
      ages: [{
        age: 4
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

const result = person.pets.flatMap(pet => pet.breeds.flatMap(b => b.ages));

console.log(result);
```